# jQuery - How to delay form submit until animation is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, delay

I have this page animation which when the user leaves the page the document slides to the left. However, I also have this form which the user fills in then hits the "Next" button, and I want the submission of the form to wait until the animation is finished (animation e3ms?)

With my mediocre knowledge of JavaScript (especially forms and parsing) I wrote a script which to my knowledge *should* work, but it's not. Any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

**JavaScript:**

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["myInput"].value;

    if(x == null || x == "") {
        $(".error-msg").animate({
            opacity: "1"
        });

        return false;
    } else {
        $("body").animate({
            "margin-left": "-200px",
            opacity: "0"
        });
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm" action="next.html" onsubmit="return ValidateForm();">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Example: johnnyappleseed@me.com">
    <span class="error-msg">You must fill out required elements!</span>

    <input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```

*CSS code just styles form and sets the .error-msg with an opacity of "0".*

P.S.: I know JavaScript form validation is dangerous, but once I publish my site I will back it up with PHP or ASP validation on my server, alongside JavaScript validation.

Comment: did you try the animation complete callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably move your ValidateForm callback onto the onclick of the submit button. Then in your callback call e.preventDefault() to stop the form submitting from the click bubbling through. After that, submit the form manually in the callback of the animation (http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**HTML**

```
<form name="myForm" action="next.html">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Example: johnnyappleseed@me.com">
    <span class="error-msg">You must fill out required elements!</span>

    <input type="submit" value="Next" onclick="ValidateForm();">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function ValidateForm() {
    // stop the form auto submitting
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["myInput"].value;

    if(x == null || x == "") {
        $(".error-msg").animate({
            opacity: "1"
        });

        return false;
    } else {
        $("body").animate({
            "margin-left": "-200px",
            opacity: "0"
        },
        {
             complete: function() { $("form[name='myForm']").submit(); }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a callback function at the end of the animation to submit the form. Try the following.

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["myInput"].value;

    if(x == null || x == "") {
        $(".error-msg").animate({
            opacity: "1"
        });
    } else {
        if ($('form').css('opacity') == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $("body").animate(
            {margin-left: "-200px",opacity: "0"},
            function() {
                $('form').submit();
            }
        );
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to just call the animation, but not post the form. :(

Comment: This must be because of the `onsubmit="return ValidateForm();`
You will need to stock the state (validated or not) of the form in a variable to know if you need to play the animation, or check the visibility of the form. I will edit my answer consequently.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not working. :/ Should I do `onclick="ValidateFOrm();` on the submit button instead of returning on the form?

Comment: Yes, Owen solution seems perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is the documentation concerning jQ animate [Here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

The last argument in your .animate parameters is the callback function which is executed when your animation is over, so yours would look like:

```
$("body").animate({
            "margin-left": "-200px",
            opacity: "0"
        }, 200, function() {
            $('form').submit();
        });
```

P.S. the 200 represents the time it takes to accomplish the animation....the default is 400.